# Java CompletableFuture "parameter"

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, completable-future

I want to call one method asynchronous and when it finishes, call other function.

What I did is:

```
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(lab::startProduction)
     .thenApplyAsync(this::productFinalized);
```

and it work! 
but my problem now is: I need to pass n parameter to the startProduction.

`startProduction(long timer)`

And I don't know which is the best way/How to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: `() -> lab.startProduction(timer)`?

Comment: gee, you even tagged your question with “[tag:lambda]” rather than “[tag:method-reference]”…

Comment: The cited question does not answer this (unless you have maybe 10 years experience with Java?)  An effective solution is: (1) code your own new class implementing Consumer<T>; (2) construct an object of that class in the calling thread - you can pass all the parameters you want in the constructor; and (3) give that object as the argument to the CompletableFuture's `thenApply` or `thenAccept` methods.